# Как прокинуть id объекта в urls.py?

Tags: python, django, generics, forms

Например example.com/send_message/{id}, чтобы при вставке id создавалась новая страница, по которой мы переходили и заполняли форму, а информация заполненная в форме отправлялась по данному id

views.py

```
class UserRatingFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "user_form_rating.html"
    model = UserFormRating
    fields = ["rating", "description"]
    success_url = "../user_rating"
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r"^user_rating/(?P<id>[\d-]+)$", UserRatingFormView.as_view(), name="user_form_rating"),
```

Comment: FormView.kwargs или как то так. В generic формах есть свойства, которое хранит переданные таким образом параметры. Можете глянуть подробнее в DetailView, как он работает